# Predicted cloud of points is tilted compared to the diagonal

Tags: regression, machine-learning, modeling

I built a model with 2 variables, i found that the predicted values for the test set did not align with their real values, so i predicted instead with the data which were used to train the model. I had the following results: [image]

I don't have a lot of experience in ML, but this shouldn't be like this. The predicted values should sit around the red line.

What could be the source of it ? Is it that my model is unsuficcient  in terms of information brought by the predictors ?

It is not an error of programming nor an error with the data as i have already looked inside of it.

Answer (score 0):

It was probably a stupid question.

Anyway here is the answer:

I made the model again, this time with all the variables i have at hand. And then only did the predicted values sit around that diagonal line (at least it is way better).
So it just means that my two-variables model doesn't bring enough information.

[image]

EDIT: Adding this 3d picture to show how the response variable vary as a function of my two explanatory variables. (z= response)

[image]

The plane show the way the regression is performed. **Could it be that it looks like the problem of regression to the mean, but is not, and simply due to the structure of the data ?**

Comment: Good question--but wrong answer.  Please see our [posts on "regression to the mean."](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%22regression%20to%20the%20mean%22&searchOn=3)  In addition to the duplicates (concerning this phenomenon with data), the figures in [my theoretical account](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/71303/919) (concerning bivariate distributions) might be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i truly don't understand. Does that mean that my response variable increments way too much in comparison to my predictors ?

Comment: I don't understand how it apply to my case. I have read many topics about regression to the means, thanks to your link, but it seems to me it is mainly about bias in the experimental design. Here, i just want to predict a variable with a model. The response variable and the independant variables were measured at the same time and place.

Comment: For exermple, this post https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/404310/386070 , as i seem to understand it, says that if a variable is caracterized by a normal distribution, then predicting it will mainly lead to predict closer to the mean.

The consequence would be: If the response variable has a normal distribution, it is useless to try to predict anything else than the mean.
Is that it ?

Comment: Your illustrations are nice examples of regression to the mean.  No other explanation is necessary.  Regression is not solely a property of bivariate Normal distributions--it is a universal phenomenon--but is most easily illustrated and explained with them.

Comment: But why does it occur specifically with my data ? Would it help if I sent you a sample of the data ?

Comment: Regression to the mean is a *mathematical* phenomenon: it occurs with *all* bivariate data, no matter how they might have been produced.

Comment: OK, then if i had only one variable in the model, it wouldn't occur, i guess. 

But why does this effect seems to disappear with overfitted model ? (60 variables instead of 2, for 200 individuals)

Comment: It doesn't disappear: it just become lesser, because "overfitted" and "high $R^2$" are nearly the same thing.

Comment: You will be starting to think i'm stubborn (or stupid) but this study here talks about RTM happening in pre-post studies, which is not my case. And any subjects talking about RTM is about pre-post or following the change in value through the occurences. 

I can't get to understand how and why it would be RTM in my case. I'm really sorry, i'm just doing by best to understand the source of the underlying problem

https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/30743311/#:~:text=Regression%20to%20the%20mean%20for%20the%20bivariate%20binomial,an%20inaccurate%20conclusion%20in%20a%20pre-post%20study%20design.

Comment: "Happening in pre-post studies" does not mean "happens *only* in pre-post studies!"

Comment: If the goal is to have good prediction performances, what would you do in my place ? Would you choose another method for predicting ? (shrinkage, variable transformation,  ensemble models...)

Looking more and more at the 3D graphics of X,Y and Predicted, i can see more and more why this regression is a natural consequence, but it is therefore not so good to predict i guess.
My final word would that this result is natural, but variable choice is wrong.

Comment: Nobody can answer that because it depends on what you're predicting, on why, and on how accurate you need your predictions to be.